# Trying to use functions in c++ to calculate if a 2D vector is perpendicular to another

Tags: c++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkC6p.png)

The picture contains what I've tried...I assume something might be wrong in the normalize function but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Please include everything needed to give a useful answer in your question(s) - hyperlinks for reference and elaboration welcome. Please prefer text over raster images, especially for textual program response and source code. Heed [How do I write a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please add code and errors as **text** ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors in text format are much, *much* better than code/errors as an image, which are somewhat better than nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error.

Answer (score 0):

Two vectors are [perpendicular/orthogonal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality#targetText=In%20Euclidean%20space%2C%20two%20vectors,to%20spaces%20of%20any%20dimension.) If their [dot product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#targetText=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20dot%20product,and%20returns%20a%20single%20number.) is zero. You don't need to normalize anything. Here's a function that checks if two vectors are perpendicular:

```
int arePerpendicular(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    double epsilon = 0.1;
    double dot = x1 * x2 + y1 * y2;
    if (abs(dot) < epsilon)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`x1` and `y1` are the first vector components, and `x2` and `y2` the second vector components. Also, `epsilon` is a threshold value, absolute values lesser than it are considered `0`. This is necessary because an explicit `== 0` check using floating point arithmetic is likely to fail due to the very nature of `float` and `double`. In fact, when comparing two floating point variables for equality you should find the absolute value of their difference and check if it's below a certain threshold.